# EE channel content - exporting

Tags: channel-entries, import, export, ee

I have my users working on a staging server updating copy and I am still working locally deploying my changes to the style etc.

The problem I have is I have installed a module or some something locally which changes the database, if I do a full dump I will losse there data.

Is there a way to export all the data from the channels for importing into my local site.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any sort of version control?

Comment: git via beanstalk, problem is the database

Comment: You should be able to dump both databases, do a diff on them and pull out the data you need. Just treat the DBs as a text file as that is essentially what they are. Then you should be able to get the information you need out of it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: You're right JG! My bad on that :)

Answer (score 1):

Exporting;

- exp_channel_data
- exp_channel_titles
- and maybe exp_channel_entries_autosave

Should get you there. Obviously back it all up first in case it goes horribly wrong.

You may also be to approach it the other way and install the add-on on the staging server and get them in synch that way. There may well be much less data to deal with.